# Free SWF file format viewer

Tags: flash

What's a good free utility to view the content of a Flash SWF file?  I'd really like to be able to import and export any resources (i.e. image data) within the file too if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sothink decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) is good one, but its not free. And i don't think u can export resources back into an swf. Thats the duty of compiler, ain't it?